# Upload file type

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've created an upload file and it won't save in database. I created the controller and the view like codeigniter tutorial says.

I put in the config the allowed_types.

```
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
```

and it continues to show me this:

```
 The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that occurs in CodeIgniter 2.1.0 and PHP v5.2.x. If you downgrade back to [CodeIgniter 2.0.3](http://downloads.codeigniter.com/reactor/CodeIgniter_2.0.3.zip), the upload problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your system/libraries/Upload.php with this one:

https://raw.github.com/narfbg/CodeIgniter/320ddaa3d01c9d8ee6832fa25f9273e2588c63dd/system/libraries/Upload.php

This is a new version of the Upload class that's currently waiting to be merged - it should fix any issue that you might have with file detection on upload.